# How to clear a remote form in Rails 3 using Coffeescript after submission?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

I'm using a remote form to submit comments in Rails. The user should *not* be sent to a new page because I'm using this remote form.

When I hit "submit" I'd like it to have a status fade in that says "Thanks for submitting" and the form clear. Yet, I can't figure out how to do this for the life of me.

The problem comes in that when I do $('form').submit -> and then clear the text area, it resets it before I actually finish the submit, so I get a blank submission in Rails.

I'm using Rails 3.2, Coffeescript and Jquery.

Comment: Can you show what you've done so far?

Comment: This isn't formatting well

$ ->
 $('.tab-pane > form').submit ->
  showStatus "Question Submitted!" 
  $('[name="broadcast[comments_attributes][0][content]"]').val('')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are wanting to do this as the form is submitted but... you use jQuery's bind (or live) method and wait for it to return success.

```
$('#submit_button')
  .live('ajax:success', clearForm)
  .live('ajax:success', notifyUser)
```

If you want to do it regardless of success, or in whatever stage of the request check out the other available ajax callbacks 'beforeSend', 'complete', 'error', etc.

Answer (score 1):

A variation on DanS' answer:

```
$('form').submit (e) ->
  e.preventDefault() # prevent form submitting multiple times
  $.post(@action, $(@).serializeArray()).done -> # manually submit the form
    $(@).find('input').each -> @reset() # afterwards clear the form
  return
```

I've added the done callback after the ajax call, this will force a wait for the ajax to complete before clearing the form.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$('form').submit (e) ->
  e.preventDefault() # prevent form submitting multiple times
  $.post @action, $(@).serializeArray() # manually submit the form
  $(@).find('input').each -> @reset() # afterwards clear the form
  return
```

And it produces the following javascript:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.post(this.action, $(this).serializeArray());
  $(this).find('input').each(function() {
    return this.reset();
  });
});
```

Comment: return false appears to be preventing it from submitting at all for some reason. Its rendering as return false; in javascript

Comment: I modified my answer with an alternative

Comment: Hmm, I feel we're really close. It appears that it isn't submitting actually until the end of the function, which is really strange. I used breakpoints, and saw that sure enough when @submit was being called, nothing popped up in the rails console until the function ended after it had already changed the value.

Answer (score 0):

Form submission **will** load a new page. If you want to keep the user on the same page and still submit the form data you must send the form manually:

```
$('form').bind 'submit', (e) ->
    e.preventDefault() # don't send the user to a new page
    $.post this.action, $(this).serializeArray() # manually submit formdata to form url
    $(this).find(':input').each -> this.reset() # reset all fields in the form
```

(I haven't tested the above, hopefully there are no errors)